# Flex-box height problems

Tags: css, flexbox

Here the CodePen: http://codepen.io/BamiGorengo/pen/vXEmXX

I got the content area and the sidebar area. i tryed to do my best, to make it totaly responsive, but the div with the class "chat" dont geht the correct height on some resolutions...

[image]

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  height: 100%; }
  html body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif; }

header {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #404040;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48); }

html body .live-chat {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex; }
  html body .live-chat .main {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column; }
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      html body .live-chat .main {
        width: 72%; } }
    html body .live-chat .main .live-video {
      background-position: 50%;
      background-color: #0c0c0c; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        html body .live-chat .main .live-video {
          padding: 0 80px; } }
      @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        html body .live-chat .main .live-video {
          padding: 0 120px; } }
      @media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
        html body .live-chat .main .live-video {
          padding: 0 240px; } }
      html body .live-chat .main .live-video img,
      html body .live-chat .main .live-video video {
        width: 100%;
        display: block; }
    html body .live-chat .main .chat {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -moz-box-orient: vertical;
      box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -moz-box-direction: normal;
      box-direction: normal;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -moz-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -moz-flex-grow: 1;
      flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1; }
      html body .live-chat .main .chat ul {
        min-height: 140px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
        -moz-flex-grow: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: #404040; }
        html body .live-chat .main .chat ul li {
          list-style: none; }
          html body .live-chat .main .chat ul li .msg {
            color: #fff; }
          html body .live-chat .main .chat ul li.me .name {
            color: #4183D7; }
          html body .live-chat .main .chat ul li.other .name {
            color: #F62459; }
      html body .live-chat .main .chat .chat-input input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px; }
  html body .live-chat .sidebar {
    width: 320px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    padding: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    right: -320px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #242424; }
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      html body .live-chat .sidebar {
        width: 28%;
        height: 100%;
        position: inherit; } }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
      html body .live-chat .sidebar {
        padding: 20px; } }
    html body .live-chat .sidebar.open {
      right: 0; }
    html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #0c0c0c;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; }
      html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget {
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          padding: 20px; } }
      html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget h1 {
        margin: 0; }
      html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget .additional-info {
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 14px; }
      html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget .user-images {
        padding: 10px 0;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; }
        html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget .user-images::after {
          clear: both;
          content: "";
          display: block; }
        html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget .user-images > div {
          float: left;
          display: block;
          margin-right: 2.35765%;
          width: 31.76157%; }
          html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget .user-images > div:last-child {
            margin-right: 0; }
          html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget .user-images > div img {
            width: 100%;
            display: block; }
      html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget a {
        padding: 6px 10px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        background-color: #F62459;
        border: 1px solid #fa7c9b;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; }
        html body .live-chat .sidebar .widget a:hover {
          background-color: #f10a44;
          border: 1px solid #fb92ac; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fun Chat</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    Logo
  </header>


  <div class="live-chat">

    <section class="main">
      <div class="live-video">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png">
      </div>
      <div class="chat">
        <ul>
          <li class="me"><span class="name">John</span> <span class="msg">Hallo?</span></li>
          <li class="other"><span class="name">John</span> <span class="msg">Hallo!</span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="chat-input">
          <input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      <section class="widget user-info">
        asd
      </section>

      <section class="widget">
        asd
      </section>

      <section class="widget">
        asd
      </section>
    </aside>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight **exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay Sorry, thinked the Screenshot, can explain it better than words. My Problem is that the Chat Div dont take the full height. The result is that the right sidebar, shrink to... But i want that everything is using everything the max height.